# python try except satement - not working as expected

Tags: python

I want to check if a user exist and if not useradd it .

```
def create_systemscripts_user():
    try:
        pwd.getpwnam('systemscripts')
    except KeyError:
        run('useradd -m -s /bin/bash systemscripts')
    return True
```

This runs fine. But the problem is it tries to create the user even if its present and thereby throwing an error

Fatal error: run() encountered an error (return code 9) while executing 'useradd -m -s /bin/bash systemscripts'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes according to the function doc  An
    exception is raised if the entry asked for cannot be found.

Comment: Where does `pwd` and `run`come from ? What are your imports?

Comment: @greole  The imports are import pwd
from fabric.api import *.The code works fine if the user is not present

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a documented 'feature' (read: bug) of python. http://bugs.python.org/issue4261. According to this bug page the error is reproducible under certain LDAP server conditions.

Can you give any more information about your system configuration?

Comment: Its using the default passwd file backend .I actually got the code snippet from a similar post in StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. My bad. I was trying to run the pwd.getpwnam check using fabric and thinking it was doing on the remote machine ; but it was just running locally .

Thanks again for looking into this.